# How to parse scientific notation provided to r as a string?

Tags: r

I have a variable in scientific notation that is been passed to my script as a string. as.numeric returns and NA when I try to convert it to numeric. However, if I provide the exact same number (without the quotes, of course) I can operate the variable normally. Is there a way to parse scientific notation that is provided as a character?

```
> varc = "4.38962*10^-8"
> as.numeric(varc)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> varn = 4.38962*10^-8 
> varn*10
[1] 4.38962e-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the `10^` into `e` using `gsub`, `parse` and `eval`uate.

```
eval(parse(text=gsub('\\*10\\^', 'e', "4.38962*10^-8")))
# [1] 4.38962e-08
```

Or `as.numeric`.

```
as.numeric(gsub('\\*10\\^', 'e', "4.38962*10^-8"))
# [1] 4.38962e-08
```

Comment: wouldn't `eval(parse("4.38962*10^-8"))` work just as well?

Comment: @jay.sf `as.numeric` would be better than `parse(eval` here.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva No, because `parse` expects a file by default.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thx, added it to the answer, not sure which is better.

Comment: @jay.sf it depends on the context. If you were using user-supplied strings then the user could supply the string `"rm(list = ls())"` which would wipe your session if you run `eval(parse(`, compared to returning an `NA` with `as.numeric`. You can only imagine the trouble that might be caused by the user supplying the string `"unlink('C:\WINDOWS', recursive = TRUE)"`. I would stay away from `eval(parse` unless you are absolutely certain about what all of your strings contain!

Comment: oh, I meant, `eval(parse(text="4.38962*10^-8"))`  you don't need the `gsub`.  But Allan's comment is fair warning not to do this!